# Before append text in div jquery

Tags: jquery, html, append, appendchild, prepend

Append text in already appended div id "txt". i have use appendChild() function,added "Testing This is" But i need "This is Testing"

> document.getElementById("txt").appendChild("This is");

Before

> Testing

After

> This is Testing

Help me

Answer (score 3):

You identified the answer in the tags you put on the question - take a look at the [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) jQuery function. Rather than adding child nodes to the element at the end, it adds them at the beginning. Assuming that `#txt` is an element that originally contains only the text node 'Testing', then this code:

```
$('#txt').prepend('This is ');
```

will give you the results you want.

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qtVxN/)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
var old_string = document.getElementById("div_id").innerHTML;
var new_string = "is Testing";
document.getElementById("div_id").innerHTML = new_string + " " + old_string;
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#txt").before("before text");
$("#txt").after("after text");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3nigma/BgmAq/12/)

or you can befit from the chaining

```
$("#txt").before("before ").after("after ");
```

Comment: As same div "txt" load image append before. How to append image